# Jest test.each not waiting for data to be available

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

I'm going around in circles trying to get a data driven test in Jest working. Although tests run async I was expecting the describes to run synchronously so the data would be set up before the main test runs. I also tried a beforeAll but this has the same problem. Is there a way to do this?

```
describe("My tests"), () => {
  let testData = Array<MyDataStructure> = [];
  describe("prepare test data", () => {
     getData.then((data) => {
        testData = data;
     });
  });

  describe("run tests", () => {
     test.each(testData)("this fails as testData  is empty array", row: MyDataStructure) => console.log(row);
     });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Wait until `getData` is done then execute the test cases.

`beforeAll` for getting data once for all tests.

`beforeEach` for re-fetch data for each `test`:

```
describe("My tests", () => {
  let testData: Array<MyDataStructure> = [];

  beforeAll(async () => { // async function
    testData = await getData(); // wait until getData is done 
  });

  describe("run tests", () => {
    test.each(testData)("this fails as testData  is empty array", (row: MyDataStructure) => console.log(row));
  });
});
```

Comment: `testData` is still not available to the `test.each` input array.  As of today, what the OP is asking is not possible, [see this GH issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9709).